# How to use tbl_regression with multinomial gee model

Tags: gtsummary, multinomial, libgee

Is there a way to present results from univariate analysis of multinomial gee model (perhaps using multgee package) using tbl_uvregression from daniel sjobergs gtsummary package?

I found a previous answer for a multinomial model:
[multinomial logistic regression results table in wide format using the gtsummary package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463878/multinomial-logistic-regression-results-table-in-wide-format-using-the-gtsummary?rq=1)

Would it be possible to do something like that for the multinomial gee model and while removing NAs from variables when running multiple univariate regressions with tbl_uvregression?

Code for running multinomial gee model from the package document for a nominal multinomial outcome:

```
library(multgee)
data(housing)   
fitmod <- nomLORgee(y ~ factor(time) * sec, data = housing, id = id, repeated = time)
```

Comment: That type of model may not be supported. Can you provide sample code that we can run on our machines to create a model? We can then assess 1. if the model is supported, and 2. if not supported, then we can assess if can be supported. (You're the first to mention a multinomial GEE model!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added a code snippet taken from the package document for running the multinomial gee model for a nominal outcome (unordered)

Comment: Thanks for updating. The issue is that the package does not support standard modeling package functions like `model.matrix()`. Oddly, they do seem to export methods for `model.frame()` and `terms()` (which is great!).

Comment: You can follow this GitHub Issue to track progress on its implementation into {broom.helpers} and {gtsummary}